# Could not get activity context in SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, android-context

I'm creating new Fragment which extends SupportMapFragment. In the past projects there was no problem getting activity context with this.getActivity() method, which is now not available. What's the problem? I've already tried invalidating caches, clean/rebuild project.

[image]

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }

        rxLocation = new RxLocation(Objects.requireNonNull(this.getActivity()));
        rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
        rxPermissions.setLogging(true);
        mCtx = this.getActivity();
    }
```

**Full fragment code:** https://pastebin.com/zpWXbGii

Answer (score 0):

Try  this
mCtx=getApplicationContext()

Comment: But getArguments still won't work. I'm curious what happened to the Fragment methods on which SupportMapFramgent is based..

Comment: getApplicationContext doesn't work also. As you can see in screenshot, only 4 methods are shown when I start to type 'g' after 'this'...

Answer (score 0):

Second invalidate helped. Turns out Android Studio is invalidating caches for currently active project. I made invalidation while another project was active with hope that all projects caches will be erased. Second time I started invalidation while this problematic project was in foreground.